# ListView items in fragment turns blank when touching another view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, nutiteq

I have a somewhat complex layout, involving multiple fragments, and a ListView in a fragment on top of a GLView.  When i end a touch(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) anywhere on screen other than the list view the textviews in the list view rows turn blank, calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() will refresh them, but then disappear again on the next touch.

```
The relevant bits of the layout:
SlidingFragmentActivity
    A SherlockFragment that fills the whole screen
         RelativeLayout
               A SherlockFragment containing LinearLayout, layout_width=WrapContent, layout_height=wrap_content, orientation=vertical
                   ImageButton, layout_width=WrapContent, layout_height=wrap_content
                   ListView(The problem view), layout_width=200, layout_height=wrap_content, background=transparent
                         Each row is a RelativeLayout containing several TextViews, with a semi-transparent background
               TextView
               ImageView
               View that Overrides onDraw(Canvas) to do custom drawing
          GLView - a Nutiteq MapView
```

Calling adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() any time a MotionEvent.ACTION_UP happens makes the problem less obvious, but that seems like an inelegant solution that wastes cpu time.

A couple screen shots that illustrate the problem(the list view in the lower right)
[image: before touch]
[image: after touch]